# Sed: find, replace and then append result to original line

Tags: sed, replace, append

I am on Mac, I want to find a pattern in lines, replace it with something, then append the resulting string to the end of the original line. Here is what I tried:

```
echo "test='123'" | sed -E  '/([^a-z])/ s/$/ \1/' 

sed: 1: "/([^a-z])/ s/$/ \1/": \1 not defined in the RE
```

What do I need to define `\1`? I thought I did it with `([^a-z])`. No?

Edit: Perhaps this code will represent better what I want:

1) `echo "test='123'" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9]//g'`

2) I want the new line = original line + line #1 above

In other words:

Before (what I get): `test='123'`

After (what I want): `test='123' =''`

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to get, but if I am guessing correctly, try `sed -E '/\([^a-zA-Z=][^a-zA-Z=]*\)/ s/$/ &/'` ? Not sure that the `\(--grouping operator--\)` in a line match carries over into the `s/regex/repl/` portion. I would move the `\( \)` into the `s/regex/repl/` part. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry I am obviously not clear. I need to find a string in the line and replace it with something (e.g. with a space). The result will be the new string. But then I need to append this new string to the original line. I probably need to edit my initial code to make it clearer.

Comment: verbal descriptions are often ambiguous. Best to show `before` and `after` exactly as you need it (with sample data). Good luck.

Comment: Added `before` and `after`

Comment: `echo "test='123'" | sed "s/$/ =''/g"` produces the output you requested. Yes, adding `/test='123/` before the `s` will fiso only those lines will be edited and all other will be printed without change. Good luck.

Comment: Well, you have to read the description too:) 
The replacement e.g. `=''` has to be extracted into a variable before replacing. It is not static. 

E.g. 
`test='123' --> test='123' ='' 

test=!@'123' --> test=!@'123'  =!@'123' `

etc

Comment: Ok, here is what almost works:
`echo "test='123'" | sed -E  'p; s/([a-zA-Z0-9])//g'`
The result is two lines, so I need to figure out how to remove the end of line between these two lines?

Comment: @alexsuv, you can't remove the newline after you have used `p`. But you can just put the line in the hold space and then append it to the edited line and get rid of the newline, as my answer shows.

Comment: Enrico, fabulous answer. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this command this way:

```
echo "test='123'" | sed -E 'h;s/([a-zA-Z0-9])//g;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/'
```

For readability, the script, line by line, reads

```
h
s/([a-zA-Z0-9])//g
G
s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1/
```

- `h` stores the current line in the hold space,
- your `s` command does what it does
- `G` appends the content of the hold space, i.e. the original line, to the pattern space, i.e. the current line as you have edited it, putting a newline `\n` in between.
- another `s` command reorders the two pieces, also removing the `\n` that the `G` command inserted.

### Comments

- Your original attempt `sed -E  '/([^a-z])/ s/$/ \1/'` could not work because `\1` refers to what is captured by the leftmost `(…)` group **in the search portion of the `s` command**, it does not "remember" the group(s) you used to address the line.
- Once you print the pattern space with `p`, a newline comes with it, and once it's been printed, there's no way you can remove it within the same `sed` program.